# How to generate localStorage data for Google Chrome extension running in Selenium driver?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, google-chrome-extension

I need to run a test in Chrome driver which loads an extension which modifies HTTP headers. This extension stores its data in `localStorage`, per profile.

I tried starting `chromedriver` with `user-data-dir` set to the profile which already has this information manually inserted, but the profile data aren't loaded during test.  What else do I need to configure to allow the Chrome extension to access `localStorage` associated with particular profile?

---

Here's some code to help illustrate the problem:

```python
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


def load_message_monitoring():
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument(
        'user-data-dir=/home/wvxvw/.config/google-chrome/Default'
    )
    chrome_options.add_argument(
        'load-extension=/home/wvxvw/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj/2.1.2_0'
    )
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        executable_path='/opt/webdriver/chromedriver',
        chrome_options=chrome_options,
    )
    driver.get('http://localhost:3000/')
    # This breaks because the extension doesn't rewrite headers
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: I think the extension should be already installed in that profile, not via chromeDriver.

Comment: @wOxxOm can you elaborate? The extension is installed in the profile being loaded. But it cannot access the data anyway.

Comment: You said "Chrome driver which loads an extension" so I've assumed you're loading it dynamically. If it's not the case, it's not clear what causes the problem.

Comment: @wOxxOm I don't know what do you mean by "load dynamically". I added the code above to illustrate the way the extension is loaded.

Comment: `load-extension=` means you're loading the extension dynamically, whereas I suggested to install the extension in the profile (using the browser).

Comment: @wOxxOm ok, nevermind, I realized that `Default` in the path to profile was not needed. Once I removed it, it was accessing the profile-related data just fine.